# Range of one-dimensional lattice paths of a given length

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, generating-functions, random-walk, integer-lattices

How many [lattice paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path) in $\mathbb{Z}$ of length $n$ with steps in $\{-1,0,+1\}$ visit $m$ distinct points?

Notice that this is just the number of lattice paths $P$ such that $\max P - \min P + 1 = m$. If this helps, the generating function for the set of paths $P$ such that $\max P = k$ seems to be

$$(M(z) z)^k (M(z) z)^* M(z)$$

where

$$M(z) = \frac{2}{1 - z + \sqrt{(1 - 3 z) (1 + z)}}$$

is the generating function for the [Motzkin numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number#Combinatorial_interpretations). The interpretation of this generating function is that one takes a left-leaning Motzkin path, moves right, takes a left-leaning Motzkin path, moves right, and so on $k$ times. Finally, one takes a left-leaning Motzkin path, moves left, takes a left-leaning Motzkin path, moves left, and so on an arbitrary number of times. Thus the final position can be anywhere to the left of the maximum.

Comment: The answer would be a random variable.  Are you looking for its probability distribution?

Comment: If divided by the total number of walks of length $n$, namely $3^n$, yes.

Comment: Do all the three steps have the same probability?

Comment: Yes, since I'm just counting the number of walks.

Comment: @user76284 What does "counting the number of walks" have to do with the assumption on the step probabilities?

Comment: Because if each step is equally likely, the probability of any walk of length $n$ is just $3^{-n}$, and thus the probability of a set of walks is just its cardinality divided by $3^n$. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: "Notice that this is just the number of lattice paths P such that maxP−minP+1=m."  I don't understand what this means?

Comment: I believe the number of distinct points visited by a path $P$ is the size of the interval $[\min P, \max P]$, since it traverses every point in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Range of a Simple Random Walk on $\mathbb{Z}$](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v21i4p10) by Bernhard Moser, the number of lattice paths in $\mathbb{Z}$ of length $n$ and range $d$ is

\begin{align}
a_{n,d}
&= (\mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_d^n \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_{d-1}^n \mathbf{1}) - (\mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_{d-1}^n \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_{d-2}^n \mathbf{1}) \\
&= \mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_d^n \mathbf{1} - 2 \cdot \mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_{d-1}^n \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{1}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{Q}_{d-2}^n \mathbf{1}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{1} =(1, \dots, 1)^\mathrm{T}$ is a vector of ones and $\mathbf{Q}_d$ is the $d \times d$ [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix)
$$
(\mathbf{Q}_d)_{ij} = [i - 1 \leq j \leq i + 1]
$$

I include the main diagonal since I have steps $\{-1,0,+1\}$ rather than $\{-1, +1\}$ as in the paper. I've checked $a_{n,d}$ numerically and this expression seems correct.